# Macro (VBA) crashing Microsoft word (Find and replace)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I using a VBA code to batch find and replace highlighted text. The macro finds and replaces the words in the document. It works well with a few number of highlighted text on a small document (1-2 pages). However, when I use this macro on a large documents which has over a 100 pages, Microsoft word crashed and becomes unresponsive so I have to forced to quit.

The code is to help make it easy to redact information. I am replacing the highlight text which occur also in tables with XXXXX and highlighted black.

Does anyone have any tips to make the code more efficient?

Here is the code

```
Sub FindandReplaceHighlight()
  Dim strFindColor As String
  Dim strReplaceColor As String
  Dim strText As String
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim objRange As Range
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
  Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
 
  strFindColor = InputBox("Specify a color (enter the value):", "Specify Highlight Color")
  strReplaceColor = InputBox("Specify a new color (enter the value):", "New Highlight Color")
  strText = InputBox("Specify a new text (enter the value):", "New Text")
  
  With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
      .Highlight = True
 
      Do While .Execute
        If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = strFindColor Then
          Set objRange = Selection.Range
          objRange.HighlightColorIndex = strReplaceColor
          objRange.Text = strText
          objRange.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
          Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End If
      Loop
    End With
  End With
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a `Do... Loop` with an `If` condition, which if it is not true will just put it into an infinite loop, which causes the program to crash. That's my best guess.

Comment: There is an add-in to Word called AuthorTec Redactor, I am the author. You can get information about it by doing a web search on the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub FindandReplaceHighlight()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ClrFnd As Long, ClrRep As Long, strTxt As String
Const StrColors As String = vbCr & _
"  1 Black" & vbCr & _
"  2  Blue" & vbCr & _
"  3  Turquoise" & vbCr & _
"  4  Bright Green" & vbCr & _
"  5  Pink" & vbCr & _
"  6  Red" & vbCr & _
"  7  Yellow" & vbCr & _
"  8  White" & vbCr & _
"  9  Dark Blue" & vbCr & _
"10 Teal" & vbCr & _
"11 Green" & vbCr & _
"12 Violet" & vbCr & _
"13 Dark Red" & vbCr & _
"14 Dark Yellow" & vbCr & _
"15 Gray 50" & vbCr & _
"16 Gray 25%"
 
ClrFnd = InputBox("Specify the old color (enter the value):" & StrColors, "Specify Highlight Color")
ClrRep = InputBox("Specify the new color (enter the value):" & StrColors, "New Highlight Color")
strTxt = InputBox("Specify the new text (enter the value):", "New Text")
  
With ActiveDocument
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Highlight = True
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      If .HighlightColorIndex = ClrFnd Then
        .HighlightColorIndex = ClrRep
        .Text = strTxt
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      End If
    Loop
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```